# JSON Material UI Select DropDown

Tags: django, reactjs, material-ui

I cannot get a material ui Drop down to populate with JSON Data. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code  that has the JSON and the code itself.

```
`
const json = {   ResponseMetadata: {
RequestId: "1B29B45E145594A7",
HostId:
  "fNB6fQZ8LQrK53j9lIOMSKy49mA8xrAMiwVh05/fKcBB5/gjYF6qUdxLFw4/zR5mRNHg2ge6t3w=",
HTTPStatusCode: 200,
HTTPHeaders: {
  "x-amz-id-2":
    "fNB6fQZ8LQrK53j9lIOMSKy49mA8xrAMiwVh05/fKcBB5/gjYF6qUdxLFw4/zR5mRNHg2ge6t3w=",
  "x-amz-request-id": "1B29B45E145594A7",
  date: "Sun, 13 May 2018 20:36:02 GMT",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  server: "AmazonS3"
},
RetryAttempts: 0   },   Buckets: [
{
  Name: "eladft-1-653237860766",
  CreationDate: "2014-09-01T16:58:41Z"
},
{
  Name: "elasticdf37860766",
  CreationDate: "2015-10-06T00:24:57Z"
},
{
  Name: "elasticdf0766",
  CreationDate: "2015-10-02T17:37:19Z"
}   ],   Owner: {
DisplayName: "dfdf",
ID: "b4bf8bde7571756284e067071dfe442c7b014a09f012a1179"   }   };
`

 <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="bucketName-simple">Buckets</InputLabel>
      <Select
        native="true"
        value={this.state.json.Buckets.Name}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          name: "v_bucketName",
          id: "age-simple"
        }}
      >
        {this.state.json.Buckets.map((Buckets, i) => (
          <MenuItem native="true" key={i} value={Buckets.Name}>
            {Buckets.Name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
        )} 
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </form>
);
 }
}
```

The data from AWS S3. But this is using Material-UI and React JS

[Code Sanbox](http://%3Ca%20href=%22https://codesandbox.io/s/k009xyml0v%22%3E%20%20%20%3Cimg%20alt=%22Edit%20k009xyml0v%22%20src=%22https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg%22%3E%20%3C/a%3E)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `native=true`. That means you can't use the `MenuItem` component. Use `<option>` instead.

See https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/#native-select.